# Updating a string with string.replace in JS

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have the following question:
I have an array ['cd', 'ef', 'kl'] and a string 'ab(AA)ef(LL)ij(EX)'. I'd like to replace the text between parentheses (AA)s with 'cd', 'ef' and 'ij' respectively to make it 'ab(cd)ef(gh)ij(kl)'. I've written a code to find text between brackets

```
var s = 'ab(cd)ef(gh)ij(kl)';
var regExp = /\((.+?)\)/g;
var found = [], r;
while(r = regExp.exec(s)) {
    found.push(r[1]);
}
```

but what should I do next? String.replace(re, found[x]) replaces all brackets with just the first one, as it should, and if I remove /g flag, it finds only the first occurrence (again, as it should). A bit stuck here, could you give me a hint please?

Comment: Confused: is `s` your desired result or the input? Your snippet does not include the array nor the string you mentioned earlier. Can you say explicitly what parameters we are given, and what you would like the result to be?

Comment: Agreed with @CRice Your code and your question don't really match up intuitively. Can you give us an example of the exact issue you're having? I don't know what "replaces all brackets with just the first one" means, for instance. Also when you say `brackets` I think you mean `parentheses`, right?

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
\([^()]+\)
```

as a regular expression and iterate over your array:

```js
var string = 'ab(AA)ef(LL)ij(EX)';
var arr = ['cd', 'ef', 'kl'];
cnt = 0;
console.log(string.replace(/\([^()]+\)/g, function() {
  return "(" + arr[cnt++] + ")";
}));
```

This yields

```
ab(cd)ef(ef)ij(kl)
```